# No CacheResolver specified, and no unique bean of type CacheManager found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis, cachemanager

I am trying to use two Different types of Cache in my Spring boot application,based on Rest API called I hvae to store data in my cache. But during project deploy stage I am getting below error.

[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
2020-06-30T11:15:17.05+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no unique bean of type CacheManager found. Mark one as primary (or give it the name 'cacheManager') or declare a specific CacheManager to use, that serves as the default one.

Can I specify @Primary on one cache manager ?I hope it does not stop storing data into another cache . Or is their a better way of doing this?

CacheConfig.java

```
@Profile("cloud")
public class CacheConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory brRedisFactory() {
    return connectionFactory().redisConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("redis_cache"));
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> brRedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(brRedisFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean(name = "firstCacheMngr")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(brRedisTemplate());
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    cacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean(name = "secondCacheMngr")
public CacheManager springCacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("secondCache")));
    return cacheManager;
}

}
```

This is how I am storing data in redis cache-

```
@Cacheable(value="redis-cache",key ="#customerId",cacheManager = "firstCacheMngr")
public CustomerInfo retriveCustomerdetails(String customerId
        String quarterEndDate)  {
     //Calling Rest API 
    }
    return customerInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can put one as @Primary and inject the another one by using @Qualifier

```
@Bean(name = "firstCacheMngr")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(brRedisTemplate());
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    cacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean(name = "secondCacheMngr")
@Primary
public CacheManager springCacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("secondCache")));
    return cacheManager;
}
```

and then use the redisCachManager as

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstCacheMngr")
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
```

Comment: any CacheManager bean require @ Primary annotation as @ Cacheable annotation allowed without 'cacheManager' field, so it goes to default which is mentioned as @Primary, make sense